# Detect if trying to remove folder in `.bash_aliases`

Tags: sh

So, in my `.bash_aliases` file, I want to create a function that will call `rm -r` if I try to just call `rm` on a directory, and vice versa for files.

```sh
function rm() {
  # What goes here?
}
```

I don't know if I would check if `$1` is a folder/file, or something else.

Comment: One problem is that you don't know that `$1` *is* the thing to delete; it could be a group of options. You also don't know that there is just one thing to delete: `rm -f someDir someOtherDir`. If you want some restricted version of `rm` that *only* takes a single item to delete and no options, I'd recommend using a different name than `rm`, at which point you may as well just remember to use `-r`.

Comment: That said, `rm () { if [ -d "$1" ]; then command rm -r "$1"; else command rm "$1"; fi; }`.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r` is quite happy to delete non-directories.

So:

```
rm(){ command rm -r "$@"; }
```